# Como ajustar a largura no background-color no ccs

Tags: html, css3

Estou com problema para ajustar o background-color de uma tabela usando css para que o fundo fique todo preto e ainda sobre uma margem para os lados, cima e baixo. A largura consigo ajustar com o width:

```
#tabela{
width: 38%;
margin: auto;  
background-color: black;
}
```

Porem a altura nao consigo com o height.

Comment: Cara não ficou claro o que vc precisa... Tem uma imagem do Layout? Vc quer mudar a altura da tabela como um todo ou só do background... ficou meio sem sentido o que vc quer fazer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar o `vh`, pode ser que você está definindo um valor em `px` ou `%` de `height` mas ele está aplicando em seu `elemento pai`, por esse motivo não aplica a altura esperada por você.

A medida `vh` é igual a `1/100` da altura da *viewport*. Então, por exemplo, se a altura do navegador é `900px`, `1vh` equivale a `9px`.

Segue exemplo:

```html
<style>
#tabela{
width: 38%;
margin: auto;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>

<div id="tabela">tabela</div>
```

Referencias: https://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/unidades-css-rem-vh-vw-vmin-vmax-ex-ch/